# How to convert this nested query into a single by query (simulating a MySql window function)?

Tags: kdb

Given the following

```
\S 1234
t:([]a:10 ? til 5; b:10 ? til 100; c:10 ? til 10000);

select a,b,c from ij[t; select maxc:max c by a from t] where c=maxc;
```

Instead of joining an inner query to use as part of the filter, is it possible to have q select the first record in each (window grouped by a and sorted by c descending)? If so, no join would be necessary.

The result would be the same. I could then do testing to see if performance if different. But mainly just trying to understand what kinds of queries are and are not possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with window joins in MySql but KDB+ does have its own variant: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/wj/ although from the example above it looks like that could be overkill for this use case

Comment: different usage of the word "window". But your answer is what I didn't know I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `fby` which matches the result of your current query

```
q)select from t where c = (max;c) fby a
a b  c
---------
2 2  5480
3 39 9473
4 77 6458
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby/

Comment: I just realized there is a problem for tied values of c within a group by a. Being able to select the first record within a group would solve that, but setting a key of `a on the result of your query would also fix it, right?

Comment: I see what you mean, you could change the query to `0!select by a from t where... `, this will cause kdb to output the last row for each a. The 0! Will then turn the resulting keyed table back into a simple table. This assumes you're OK with `b` being the last `b` for each distinct `a`.

Comment: If it would be the last `b` for each distinct `a` with maximal `c`, then perfect.

Comment: I think that should be what you're looking for then.